# Wrong _serializedATN first element value in generated lexer

Tags: c#

I'm using VS2010 Exp. C# XP SP3 environment

My current issue is with SerializedVersion value

```
Run-Time ERROR: System.TypeInitializationException: 
The type initializer for 'Antlr4.Runtime.Verilog2001Lexer' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Could not deserialize ATN with version 5 (expected 3).
```

I found the root cause but I don’t know a work around so I’m stuck

ATNSimulator.cs:

```
public abstract class ATNSimulator
{
    public static readonly int SerializedVersion = 3;
       …………………

    public static ATN Deserialize(char[] data, bool optimize)
    {
        data = (char[])data.Clone();
        // don't adjust the first value since that's the version number
        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (char)(data[i] - 2);
        }
        int p = 0;
        int version = ToInt(data[p++]);
        if (version != SerializedVersion)      <<<<<< mismatch 5 vs. 3
        {
```

But in the generated lexer

```
  {     public static readonly string _serializedATN =
              "\x5\x4\xB5\x638\b\x1\x4\x2\t\x2\x4\x3\t\x3\x4\x4\t\x4\x4\x5\t\x5\x4\x6"+ }
```

Any comment is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: The root cause is that your serialized data does not match the version of the deserializer. Either serialize the data again, with the correct deserializer, or switch deserializer version.

Comment: Thanks.i started my  project with "master" zip. i don't know the dependencies so i don't know how to implement your instructions. can you please educate me ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, to be honest I have no idea how to use that particular software package. I'm only interpreting the error message. It seems that the data you're trying to deserialize was serialized with a newer version of the Antlr package, and that you're trying to deserialize it with an older package, and thus there's a mismatch between what the deserialization code supports and what you're giving it. From where did you obtain the data you're trying to deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

This situation means you generated your lexer with an old release of the C# target, but are running the code with a new release. If you recently updated the library in your project, a Clean+Build will regenerate the grammars with the proper target.

If you followed these instructions, reinstall the antlr4 add-ons from NuGet.

https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs